# Can a for loop be incremented by a multiplication?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to console.log a set of numbers that are incremented by multiplication or how one can increase or decrease the increment of a for loop with something other than `i++, ++i, i+=3`

yes, I've looked everywhere for this, but maybe I'm thinking about a wrong loop or method.
Every time I try to run this code it won't stop and it crashes my browser so I can't play around with it anymore to try to figure out what's wrong.

```
for (let ok = 2; ok < 100; ok * 3) {console.log(ok)}
```

My question is, why does the limit of 100 not work and how to multiply and `console.log` those numbers?

Comment: Hint: `++` modifies the variable in place, `*` does not… Look closely at your own examples: `i++`, `++i`, ***`i+=3`***.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```js
for (let ok = 2; ok < 100; ok *= 3) {console.log(ok)}
```

Why does this work? Because `x *= y` is short for the reassignment statement: `x = x * y`. Your code is not increasing the value of `ok`; on every single iteration, you're just going to get `2 * 3`, because `ok` is still 2. That's why your loop never ends - it never approaches 100.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ok*=3`since variable ok won't be updated with your statement

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work, yeah

```js
for (let ok = 2; ok < 100; ok = ok * 3) {console.log(ok)}
```

Edit: To precise why this works, the [final-expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) is a piece of code that is fired at the end of every loop, so you could even make it a function call if you wanted. But be careful of infinite loops

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
for (let ok = 2; ok < 100; ok *= 3) {console.log(ok)}
```

This is the other way to write it:

```
for (let ok = 2; ok < 100; ok = ok * 3) {console.log(ok)}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is currently just multiplying `ok` by 3 but not setting `ok` to be the new value. This means the code runs forever as `ok` is not being increased.
Instead try something like:

```py
for (let ok = 2; ok < 100; ok = ok * 3) {console.log(ok)}
```

or the equivalent:

```py
for (let ok = 2; ok < 100; ok =* 3) {console.log(ok)}
```